# Allow 'load more' function to work with tag filter system

Tags: javascript, jquery, frontend

On page load, this function makes it so only 4 divs (out of a lot more) are visible. 4 more appear when a "load more" button is pressed. this can be done until all of the (80) divs, are visible.

```
$(function () {
    $(".card").slice(0, 4).addClass('display');
    $("#loadMore").on('click', function (e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        $(".card:hidden").slice(0, 4).addClass('display');
        if ($(".card:hidden").length == 0) {
           $("#loadMore").remove();
        } else {
            $('html,body').animate({
                scrollTop: $(this).offset().top
            }, 1500);
        }
    });
});
```

There's another function that allows users to filter through the 80 divs:

```
$(".portfolio-flters li").click ( function() {
    $(".card").slice(0, 4).addClass('display');
    $("#loadMore").on('click', function (e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        $(".card:hidden").slice(0, 4).addClass('display');
        if ($(".card:hidden").length == 0) {
           $("#loadMore").remove();
        } else {
            $('html,body').animate({
                scrollTop: $(this).offset().top
            }, 1500);
        }
    });
  });
```

However, upon clicking on any of the filter options, all of the divs that were initially hidden, appear.

Is there a way to make it so that when a filter option is clicked, the "load more" function still works?

(*I possess essentially no knowledge of JS or JQuery)
Thank you & have a great day!

Comment: can you please paste in your html too..

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.